# Could we have an official preference on English question title capitalization?

Tags: feature-request, title, guidelines, capitalization, english

The consensus on the preferred capitalization of English question titles in the Stack Exchange network is sentence case (Would this be an OK example?), not title case (Would This Be an OK Example?). Would it be possible to establish an official convention on the matter?

I believe that would help to resolve the kind of conflict when a user edits a question title to one convention and another user wants to revert it back to the original convention. I have [brought this up (and gave proof of the consensus)](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1650/15347) at a site, because I'm involved in this kind of a conflict, but there has been no satisfactory resolution.

There's the similar question *[What should be the default title case for non-technical questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314924/what-should-be-the-default-title-case-for-non-technical-questions)* but it also suggests automatic conversion to a capitalization convention, which is more extreme.

Comment: Only if we all agree to stick to English in the Posts.

Comment: If even one site on its own can't agree, how are we to get all sites to agree?

Comment: @RobertLongson Perhaps on that one site there were not enough people who cared, whereas overall there might be.

Comment: They might care, they might not, but even those that do care might well not agree.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [What should be the default title case for non-technical questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314924/295232)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The consensus on how to capitalize question titles in the Stack Exchange network is to use sentence case

Really? I've never come across that consensus. It is likely that the majority of users apply sentence case, mostly because they didn't know Title Case was a thing.

I'm not a fan of conventions / official preference when the only way to express your self is a matter of text and the accompanying writing style. If a post is helped by having Title Case then I should be able to do so. Similar to if I prefer to bring colour to my posts by using proper English.

The only case where I can see a back-and-forth with title edits is worthwhile is when the title isn't Sentence Case nor Title case. You could then argue it is grammatical (?) incorrect. A comment can then help to establish what form was meant and then edited once to get in the right shape. And if the response is *tHe titLe is FINE* then write it off on a broken keyboard and move on.

None of the answers here [Capitalizing titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98066/capitalizing-titles) or here [What should be the default title case for non-technical questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314924/what-should-be-the-default-title-case-for-non-technical-questionsargue) mention that title case should be forbidden. They argue it is an uncommon style, old fashioned, not fit for online use. They argue the title is harder to read. It is my decision how much effort the reader needs  to put in to consume my title. I'm very much opposing to giving the community a convention /preference stick to go beat Title Case into submission.

There is no conflict to resolve. Both sentence case and Title Case are valid title forms. If you want to get rid of that, start with the committees / publishers  that establish the common spelling, grammar and style rules. Once it is eradicated from their guidance we can start here.

Comment: Curiously, when I first started participating at [christianity.se] I had a title-case title edited to sentence-case and a comment indicating it was the way things should be. While I personally don't care either way (if title- vs sentence-case is the biggest issue one has with SE, then one is doing great!), there is an unofficial preference.

Comment: I accepted this answer, because it is true that having an official preference or convention might do more harm than good (especially if we want to be more welcoming to newcomers). I do still think that there is a consensus for sentence case, and that it may create a conflict if there are mass edits by one user changing the title capitalizations against the consensus at a scale that statistically doubles the number of questions that have the non-consensus capitalization. I do not know how such a conflict could be resolved. I do not agree that most users likely do not know about Title Case.